# What are the rules for what Chrome and Firefox considers a third-party cookie?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I have web applications running on gala.apples.mydomain.com and oranges.mydomain.com.

oranges.mydomain.com has a cookie stored on its domain only, and I want to embed it into gala.apples.mydomain.com using an iframe.

Even with third-party cookies being blocked in Chrome and Firefox, both browsers still allow oranges.mydomain.com's cookies to be passed when in an iframe inside of gala.apples.mydomain.com.

I thought this would be blocked, and work similarly to how CORS considers these two separate origins.

I can't find any rules about how a cookie is considered third-party or not.

Answer (score 2):

The details of this can be browser-dependent, as blocking third-party cookies is not the default behavior and is not mandated by any specification, unlike the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), which is essential for the security of the web.

For Firefox, the only documentation I'm aware of is in the source code: [mozIThirdPartyUtil.idl](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/597a69c70a5cce6f42f159eb54ad1ef6745f5432/netwerk/base/mozIThirdPartyUtil.idl#17).

It confirms that different subdomains of a "base domain" are not considered third-party to each other. The reason, I guess, is that:

- The point of this preference is to combat tracking the user across different web properties, which requires the tracker to reside on a separate "base" domain, so the current lax definition of third-party is enough for this.
- Being more restrictive would break even more valid uses.